# Unable to access merge field values inside visualforce component in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, visualforce

View:

```
<div ng-controller = "ClPortalRegistrationController">

    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in ObjectApiFieldsetMap">
        {{key}}  {{value}} //this is printing correct result
        <c:FieldSetComponent objectAPIName="'{{key}}'" fieldSet="'{{value}}'" cid="'{{key}}'" 
                             sectionTitle="Section 1" columns="2" textAlign="center"></c:FieldSetComponent>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.ObjectApiFieldsetMap = {
 Applications__c: "Application_FieldSet_One",
 clcommon__Collateral__c: "Collateral_FieldSet_One"
};
```

Now when I'm trying to access `{{key}},{{value}}` inside `c:FieldSetComponent`  ,its only passing string as `{{key}}` and `{{value}}` and not the converted result. How can I access values stored inside key, value inside component?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution which I implemented as a work around.

Turns out that you cannot access angular merge field values inside visualforce components. So instead of manipulating(segregating input into key-value pair) values inside angular controller, I have to push the logic to apex controller.

```
<apex:component controller="RegistrationController" access="global">
   <apex:repeat value="{!ObjectApiFieldsetMap}" var="apiName"> 
          <c:FieldSetComponent objectAPIName="{!apiName}" fieldSet="{!ObjectApiFieldsetMap[apiName]}"  
             cid="{!apiName}{!ObjectApiFieldsetMap[apiName]}" 
              columns="1" textAlign="center">
          </c:FieldSetComponent> 

   </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

And in my apex controller i.e RegistrationController , I have set the logic to segregate key values from a map input which I'm using inside visualforce component

```
global class RegistrationController {

global Map<String,String> ObjectApiFieldsetMap { 
                              get {
                                   ObjectApiFieldsetMap = arrangeApiFieldSetsByOrder();
                                   return ObjectApiFieldsetMap;
                                   } 
                                   set; 
    }

    global Map<String,String> arrangeApiFieldSetsByOrder() {

        Map<String,String> ObjectApiFieldsetMap =  new Map<String,String>();
                   /* logic for segregation */
        return ObjectApiFieldsetMap;
    }
}
```